# Neural Network - Multiple output nodes have same value

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am using a neural networks for reinforcement learning. I have a neural network with 4 output nodes and I mapped every output node to a different action. Hidden and output nodes use the sigmoid activation function.

A problem which I face is that on some inputs, few output nodes have same value (i.e. they have output value of 1). I am not sure what to do in this situation. Is there some way I could fix this, so no two output nodes have same value? Or just to randomly choose between actions which are assigned to output nodes with the highest value?

Comment: It's quite rare to have multipe nodes having exactly the same output (exactly 1 in your case)

Comment: That was also my initial assumption, but when I printed outputs this happened too often and I think it slows down training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your setup (i.e. one output per action), some ties will be unavoidable. That said, there are a few things you can do to alleviate the problem.

1. You can reduce the chance of ties by choosing an activation function for your output nodes that does not saturate like a sigmoid. For example, you may try a Rectified Linear activation function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)).
2. You can make your sigmoid less steep by multiplying the input to the sigmoid by a constant smaller than 1.
3. You can try to apply a softmax function to your output layer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). Note that if you choose to do so, you should not apply your sigmoid activation to the output layer, because the softmax function only exaggerates existing differences.
4. When you do have a tie, you can either pick an action at random (as you suggested yourself), or you can simply pick the first action in your list. This last option does bias whatever learning algorithm you have towards trying the first action, but if your learning algorithm is effective enough, it should eventually learn in which cases this is the wrong action to take, and thus learn to put less emphasis on these actions.

Alternatively, you can try a completely different way of processing your outputs (this depends on your problem domain though). For example, if your four actions are "move north", "move east", "move south", and "move west", you can instead give the network two outputs, one determining whether to move horizontal or vertical (thus splitting the actions into "move north or south" and "move east or west"), and the second output providing the tiebreaker between the remaining alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for such elaborate answer